# Setting pagination in nestacms

Tags: ruby, pagination, nestacms

I'm using nestacms for a new website.

I'm trying to add pagination where i'm listing articles.

There's no documentation on the official website.

I've tried with following gems :

- will_paginate
- kaminary

But I don't get it.

Do somone knows how to add pagination on nestacms ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is quite complicated.
As far as you don't have write access to Nesta controllers and Nesta doesn't use any database, you cannot use pagination gems.

As quick-and-dirty solution I made some changes in /views/summaries.haml

```
- unless pages.empty?
  - per_page = 10
  - page = params[:page].nil? ? 1 : params[:page].to_i
  - start_page = (page - 1) * per_page
  - end_page = page * per_page - 1

  - all_pages = Nesta::Page.find_articles
  - pages = all_pages[start_page..end_page]
  %ol
```

...*unchanged code here*

```
        = haml :page_meta, :layout => false, :locals => { :page => page }

  -if page*per_page < all_pages.size
    %a.perv{href:"/?page=#{page+1}"} Previous page
  -if page > 1
    %a.next{href:"/?page=#{page-1}"} Next page
```

Then you could adjust your .prev and .next classes as you like with CSS

As very proper solution I would suggest to make a pull request to Nesta repository with any pagination gem support by default.